# Why we have not closed the descriptor pointing to a file?

Tags: php

I am new to php. When i was reading the use of proc_open() to execute a command from php from its offical document, i found this example:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
?>
```

**Why we have not closed the 3rd (pipes[2]) file descriptor using fclose() or it will autometically closed?**

I tried to close it but then it gives warning :

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in test.php on line 121  
PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in test.php on line 121
```

Comment: If you use path to file and `file` type descriptor, `proc_open()` will handle all operations on this file so you don't get back a resource which you can write to or read from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. You can close only std* pipes. When you opened with standard pipes:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
       0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
       1 => array("file", 'dump.log', "w"),  // file instead stdout
       2 => array("pipe", "a")
    );
$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

print_r($pipes);
```

And you will see something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Resource id #5
    [2] => Resource id #6
)
```

So $pipes[1] will be not available.

Based on php source code it looks as only "pipe" is falling to $pipes array.

For pipes: php is used "pipe" call on C. Since pipe descriptor is shared between processes, and operation system can close pipe only in that case, if no process is using the pipe. "On a technical note, the EOF will never be returned if the unnecessary ends of the pipe are not explicitly closed." - http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html

Comment: i want to ask that if we open a file using "fopen" then we close it using "fclose" , but in this case also we are opening a file for writing , why we are not closing it , or php close it automatically?If automatically then any special reason why not it close other descriptors too automatically , for any security reason or something else?

Comment: Yes, php will close automatically "no pipe" resources. Regarding for pipes - I have updated an answer.